# Getting unique values from 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays that I'm trying to get the unique values only from them. So I'm not just trying to remove duplicates, I'm actually trying to remove both duplicates.

So if I'm getting the 2 arrays like this:

```
$array1 = array();
$array2 = array();

foreach($values1 as $value1){ //output: $array1 = 10, 15, 20, 25;
    $array1[] = $value1;
}   

foreach($values2 as $value2){ //output: $array2 = 10, 15, 100, 150;
    $array2[] = $value2;
}
```

The final output I'm looking for is

```
$output = 20, 25, 100, 150;
```

Any neat way to getting this done?

Comment: Are those arrays truly arrays, or are they maps? To make my question clearer, are your keys 0,1,2,... or are they words and such?

Comment: @codersarepeople They're not array maps. They're individual separate arrays containing numbers. One could be 3 values and the other 10 values. Just coincidence that they're both 4.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The other answers are on the right track, but [`array_diff`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) only works in one direction -- ie. it returns the values that exist in the first array given that aren't in any others.

What you want to do is get the difference in both directions and then merge the differences together:

```
$array1 = array(10, 15, 20, 25);
$array2 = array(10, 15, 100, 150);
$output = array_merge(array_diff($array1, $array2), array_diff($array2, $array1));
// $output will be (20, 25, 100, 150);
```

Answer (score 8):

Not to detract from Daniel Vandersluis's answer, but to add to it...

What you're looking for is basically an XOR operation of the arrays.  To that end, "merlinyoda at dorproject dot net" provided the following routine, in a comment on http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php :

```
<?php
function array_xor ($array_a, $array_b) {
    $union_array = array_merge($array_a, $array_b);
    $intersect_array = array_intersect($array_a, $array_b);
    return array_diff($union_array, $intersect_array)
}
?>
```

This function takes a different approach to calculating the XOR.

Comment: Worth noting that Daniel Vandersluis's answers resets the array with its own keys - this method actually preserves keys so you can end up with an array with keys 1,2,3,5,7,8,11 etc.

Answer (score 5):

Try following code it works fine for numbers,String and every condition

The following Logic will only works for **numbers**.

```
$array1 = array(10, 15, 20, 25);
$array2 = array(10, 15, 100, 150);
$output = array_merge(array_diff($array1, $array2), array_diff($array2, $array1));
```

The following logic will work fine for **any condition**

```
$a1 = array('1@gmail.com'); 
$a2 = array('1@gmail.com','2@gmail.com');
$new_array=array_merge($a1,$a2);
$unique=array_unique($new_array);
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Note also, that what's "above" and "below" depends very much on how you are viewing the question - there's no natural order for answers.

Comment: Give positive vote to the above answer so that reader will easily get the correct answers

Answer (score 4):

Here is the code to do it. It may be able to be optimized, but you get the idea:

```
$array1 = array(10, 15, 20, 25);
$array2 = array(10, 15, 100, 150);

$new_array = array();
foreach($array1 as $value) {
    if(!in_array($value, $array2)) {
        array_push($new_array, $value);
    }
}
foreach($array2 as $value) {
    if(!in_array($value, $array1)) {
        array_push($new_array, $value);
    }
}

print_r($new_array);
```

To use array_diff, you would have to do:

```
$array1 = array(10, 15, 20, 25);
$array2 = array(10, 15, 100, 150);

$out1 = array_diff($array1, $array2);
$out2 = array_diff($array2, $array1);
$output = array_merge($out1, $out2);

print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another good solution is this:

> $array1 = array(10, 15, 20, 25);
>
> $array2 = array(10, 15, 100, 150);
>
> $output = array_diff(array_merge($array1, $array2), array_intersect($array1, $array2));
>
> // $output will be (20, 25, 100, 150);

Answer (score 1):

The `array_diff()` ([manual](http://php.net/array_diff)) function can be used to find the difference between two arrays:

```
$array1 = array(10, 20, 40, 80);
$array2 = array(10, 20, 100, 200);
$diff = array_diff($array1, $array2);
// $diff = array(40, 80, 100, 200);
```

You can pass as many arrays as you want to the function, it is not just limited to two arrays.

Comment: Incorrect -- with your code, `$diff` will be `array(40, 80)`. `array_diff` only works in one direction. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_merge` and `array_unique` like below:

```
$array1 = array(10, 15, 20, 25);
$array2 = array(10, 15, 100, 150);
$output = array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2));
```

This is simple and easy to understand.

Answer (score -1):

see [array_diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
$output = array_diff($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: This won't give you the result you're expecting, because `array_diff` only returns the values that are only in the first array. See my answer for more details.

Comment: This will only return the difference from array 1 to array 2 meaning that it will only show the items from array1 that do not exist in array2. You would have to compare both sets of arrays.