# php array comparison using diff and intersect seems not giving the result i need

Tags: php, arrays, compare, array-intersect

I have 2 arrays

```
$a = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
$b = array("3", "4", "5", "6", "7");
```

I want the final result be ("6", "7")

It seems that `array_diff()` and `array_intersect()` can't give the result that I need.

Comment: "6" and "7' are values that are in the second array and not in first, right?

Comment: You can check this theme here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507419/getting-unique-values-from-2-arrays

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use [`array_diff`](http://php.net/array_diff), what's your problem?

```
$arrayA = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5");
$arrayB = array("3", "4", "5", "6", "7");
$result = array_diff($arrayB, $arrayA);
```

Docs:

> #### Return Values
>
> Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

([codepad example](http://codepad.org/KbUaVIZq))