# How to merge two array without items that exists in both arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having 2 arrays:

```
$arr_1 = ['1','2','3','4'];

$arr_2 = ['2','5','4','6','7'];
```

I want to merge `$arr_1` and `$arr_2` with out exists item in both of these arrays like:

```
$arr_merged = ['1','3','5','6','7']
```

How could I do that? I think I have to run some foreach to loop through these arrays and handle, but it's looks like not a really good resolution for this problem...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting unique values from 2 arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507419/getting-unique-values-from-2-arrays) ie: http://ideone.com/xR6Fk5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For getting unique items, the `array_diff()` function can be used to find the difference between two arrays. It computes the difference of all the arrays and returns all the arrays that do contains entries that cannot be matched in any of the arrays. And for merging two arrays you can use `array_merge()` function.

```
<?php
    $arr_1 = ['1','2','3','4'];
    $arr_2 = ['2','5','4','6','7'];
    $arr_merged  = array_merge(array_diff($arr_1, $arr_2), array_diff($arr_2, $arr_1));
    print_r($arr_merged);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You use `array_diff` along with `array_merge` to achieve the output.

Note: `array_diff` is technically not the opposite of `array_intersect`.

```
   <?php
        $arr_1 = ['1','2','3','4'];
        $arr_2 = ['2','5','4','6','7'];
        $diff_1 = array_diff($arr_1, $arr_2);
        $diff_2 = array_diff($arr_2, $arr_1);
        $array_merge = array_merge($diff_1,$diff_2);
        print_r($array_merge);
    ?>
```