# find unique array from 2 array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've 2 array in my php code

```
$array_1 = array(
     array('id'=>1, 'roll'=>145),
     array('id'=>2, 'roll'=>14),
     array('id'=>5, 'roll'=>1),
)
```

**second array**

```
$array_2 = array(
     array('id'=>1, 'roll'=>145, 'name'=>'A'),
     array('id'=>4, 'roll'=>189, 'name'=>'B'),
     array('id'=>5, 'roll'=>1, 'name'=>'C'),
     array('id'=>3, 'roll'=>744, 'name'=>'D'),
)
```

**expected outcome**

```
$outcome = array(
     array('id'=>4, 'roll'=>189, 'name'=>'B'),
     array('id'=>3, 'roll'=>744, 'name'=>'D'),
);
```

**tried these methods, but they are not working**

- array_unique
- array_diff

Comment: Your expected outcome is based on what condition(s)?

Comment: i want to find the difference of 2 array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077840/difference-between-two-arrays)

Comment: based on... `id`, `roll`, `name`, combination thereof? Just asking as the I don't understand why `id=>5` is _different_ because `id=>5` `roll=>1` exists in both arrays.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3507472/6662773

Comment: @jibsteroos it has to map id and roll and then find the difference

Comment: @Jaymin i've an associative array

Comment: @runningmark Your first array has `array('id'=>5, 'roll'=>1)` and second array has `array('id'=>5, 'roll'=>1, 'name'=>'C')`. What is the difference?

Comment: @vivek_23 i want to omit values which are common in array_1 and array_2

Comment: @runningmark Then why your expected result has `array('id'=>5, 'roll'=>1, 'name'=>'C')`?

Comment: @vivek_23 updated the question :) sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 1):

To find all rows that are not present in second array of the 2 arrays based on combination of `id` and `roll`, you can create an associative array which holds all the IDs as keys and intern has it's own array where the keys are it's roll numbers.

Below is an example of the sample array and how it's associative array (say `$map`) would look like:

```
$array_1 = array(
     array('id'=> 1, 'roll'=> 145),
     array('id'=> 2, 'roll'=> 14),
     array('id'=> 5, 'roll'=> 1),
);

Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [145] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [14] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1
        )

)
```

Now, you can just loop over the second array and check with `isset` function and collect all results that doesn't satisfy the `isset` condition.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$array_1 = array(
     array('id'=> 1, 'roll'=> 145),
     array('id'=> 2, 'roll'=> 14),
     array('id'=> 5, 'roll'=> 1),
);

$array_2 = array(
     array('id'=> 1, 'roll'=> 145, 'name'=>'A'),
     array('id'=> 4, 'roll'=> 189, 'name'=>'B'),
     array('id'=> 5, 'roll'=> 1, 'name'=>'C'),
     array('id'=> 3, 'roll'=> 744, 'name'=>'D'),
);


$map = [];

foreach($array_1 as $curr_data){
    if(!isset($map[$curr_data['id']])) $map[$curr_data['id']] = [];
    $map[$curr_data['id']][$curr_data['roll']] = true;
}

$result = [];

foreach($array_2 as $curr_data){
    if(!isset($map[$curr_data['id']],$map[$curr_data['id']][$curr_data['roll']])) $result[] = $curr_data;
}

print_r($result);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/kUshn

Comment: `id=>2` `roll=>14` exists only in the first array, is it not supposed to get included in the _unique_ results array?

Comment: @jibsteroos Interesting question. Looks like OP only wants to retrieve results according to second array since it has an extra `name` key. Will surely update my answer if OP clarifies the same.

Comment: @runningmark Would you like `id => 2,roll => 14` in your final results?

Comment: no, since the first array data is coming from the database and second array, the data is coming from user filled form!

Comment: @runningmark Ok, then the current solution should work for you.

Comment: @jibsteroos Apparently, OP wants only rows from 2nd array that are not present in first array.

Comment: Yep, wasn't completely clear at first... :-) Well done on your solution!

Comment: @jibsteroos _Yep, wasn't completely clear at first_ For me too :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use next `foreach` loop with help of [in_array()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [unset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) functions:

```
foreach($array_2 as $ind => $ar){
    if (in_array($ar['id'],array_column($array_1,'id'))) unset($array_2[$ind]);
}

sort($array_2);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/MHfO1)

If you wanna retrieve resultant array based on the same `id` and `roll` use next `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($array_2 as $ind => $ar){
    if (in_array($ar['id'],array_column($array_1,'id')) && 
        in_array($ar['roll'],array_column($array_1,'roll'))) unset($array_2[$ind]);
}

sort($array_2);
```

[Demo2](https://3v4l.org/WiNBB)

Answer (score 0):

Given your examples, if we reindex each array by id (using array_column), and then find the difference between keys we'll get the answer you desire:

```
<?php

$array_1 = array(
     array('id'=>1, 'roll'=>145),
     array('id'=>2, 'roll'=>14),
     array('id'=>5, 'roll'=>1),
);

$array_2 = array(
     array('id'=>1, 'roll'=>145, 'name'=>'A'),
     array('id'=>4, 'roll'=>189, 'name'=>'B'),
     array('id'=>5, 'roll'=>1, 'name'=>'C'),
     array('id'=>3, 'roll'=>744, 'name'=>'D'),
);

$out = array_diff_key(
    array_column($array_2, null, 'id'), 
    array_column($array_1, null, 'id')
);

var_export($out);
```

Output:

```
array (
    4 => 
    array (
      'id' => 4,
      'roll' => 189,
      'name' => 'B',
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'id' => 3,
      'roll' => 744,
      'name' => 'D',
    ),
  )
```

You can re-index if you desire using `array_values($out)`.

Comment: Of course if your id and roll pairs differ in each array, you might get an unexpected result.